# JsArray<?> has size 1 but getting "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0"

Tags: java, gwt

I start to lose my sanity to this ..

All I am trying to do is excluding a certain `Node` from  a `NodeList`

```
private List<Node> excludeDraggedElement(JsArray<Node> jsNodeList) {

    List<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<>();

    GWT.log(jsNodeList.length() + ""); // Prints: 1

    for(int i = 0; i < jsNodeList.length(); i++) {

        Element element = (Element)nodeList.get(i);

        if(element == this.draggedElement.getElement()) {
            continue;
        }           
        nodeList.add(jsNodeList.get(i));
    }

    return nodeList;
}
```

The output, as you would expect, is:

```
1
Uncaught java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

I have also tried to use `splice`

```
public native void remove(JsArray<?> removeFrom, int index, int count) /*-{
    removeFrom.splice(index, count);
}-*/;
```

But this is [giving me another error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229909/getting-uncaught-typeerror-arr-0-g-splice-is-not-a-function):

```
Uncaught TypeError: arr_0_g$.splice is not a function
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Java is not Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nodeList is empty. So `nodeList.get(i)` throws an exception.

Comment: I have no more to say than: fml